# How to check a model's attribute's value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey and thanks for taking a sec to check out my question.  Rails newb here and this should be easy but I have worked myself into total confusion.

I am trying to check if a boolean attribute of my model is set to false and if so, update it to true.  Here is what I have now:

```
if @subscriber[ is_active: false ]

   @subscriber.update(is_active: true) 

   render 'exists_add'
end
```

I know this has to be a silly question but for some reason I cannot find a good answer in the docs or through Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails adds predicate methods to all your models attributes. So you can do this to any attribute. `model.attribute_name?`. Notice the question mark in the end. The same is also true for boolean methods. So you should be able to just do the following.

```
@subscriber.is_active?
```

Using your example:

```
@subscriber.update(is_active: true) unless @subscriber.is_active?
```

Comment: `Rails adds predicate methods to all your models attributes` ? Is that true? I just tried and didn't work. May be you mean to say *all boolean attributes*

Comment: While @subscriber.is_active? was returning false when I needed the opposite, it was enough to get me there.  Using !@subscriber.is_active? is now working like a charm!

Comment: @KirtiThorat No, I do mean what I said. It adds predicate methods to all attributes. Are you sure you are calling an existing attribute? What error do you get?

Comment: @Khundawg that's because I used the `unless` keyword in my example, not the `if`. `unless` saves you from having to do `if !`

Comment: Yes, I tried on existing attribute. It worked for only `boolean` attribute and all others give undefined method error.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Errr... I think you are doing it wrong. Are you calling `@instance.attribute_name?` ? I'm not making this up. :)

Comment: @KirtiThorat here, see for yourself: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/ba56fa9d-b064-46cd-8943-4711d6e69d62/a240682e31d86ddbaacd90ef7c6f711c

Comment: @Mohamad Yep, I was still using the if. This is my first non-tutorial based project so I was too giddy and missed the unless switch around.

Comment: +1 Oh..my bad..I was checking on dummy table..I didn't realize that I emptied it an sometime back.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `Subscriber` model with attribute `is_active`.

Then, you could do this:

```
unless @subscriber.is_active    
   @subscriber.update(is_active: true)    
   render 'exists_add'
end
```

Provided you have set `@subscriber` and it points to a record in `subscribers` table.